# traefik entire wildcard certificate chain configuration

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik, consul

We have a Docker Swarm Cluster with Consul + Traefik as a proxy for our microservices. Traefik v1.6.1 was installed and now we have to configure de wildcard certificate I have the own wild card certificate. This certificate is a wildcard certificate (*.mydomain.com) to support our micro services availables in subdomains as "microservice2.mydomain.com".
Cureently my configuration works with ACme certificates very well. SInce I have my own certificates now,
currently I do not find documentation of how to store the certificate in secrets or consul and how to make it work with command line arguements and docker labels as below?
How can I add certificates in the below configuration to make it work

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  traefik_init:
    image: traefik:1.6
    command:
      - "storeconfig"
      - "--api"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS"
      - "--defaultentrypoints=http,https"
      - "--acme"
      - "--acme.storage=traefik/acme/account"
      - "--acme.entryPoint=https"
      - "--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http"
      - "--acme.onHostRule=true"
      - "--acme.onDemand=false"
      - "--acme.email=foobar@example.com"
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmMode"
      - "--docker.domain=mydomain.com"
      - "--docker.watch"
      - "--consul"
      - "--consul.endpoint=consul:8500"
      - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
      - "--debug"
    networks:
      - internal
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - consul
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.6
    depends_on:
      - traefik_init
      - consul
    command:
      - "--consul"
      - "--consul.endpoint=consul:8500"
      - "--consul.prefix=traefik"
      - "--logLevel=DEBUG"
      - "--api"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https"
      - "--entrypoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS"
      - "--defaultentrypoints=http,https"
      - "--acme"
      - "--acme.storage=traefik/acme/account"
      - "--acme.entryPoint=https"
      - "--acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=http"
      - "--acme.onHostRule=true"
      - "--acme.onDemand=false"
      - "--acme.email=foobar@example.com"
      - "--docker"
      - "--docker.swarmMode"
      - "--docker.domain=mydomain.com"
      - "--docker.watch"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - internal
      - traefik_proxy
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.backend=traefik"
            - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.mydomain.com"
            - "traefik.port=8080"
            - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"

  consul:
    image: consul:latest
    command: "agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -ui -client 0.0.0.0 -bind '{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}'"
    volumes:
      - consul-data:/consul/data
    environment:
      - CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={"datacenter":"us_east2","server":true}
      - CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE=eth0
      - CONSUL_CLIENT_INTERFACE=eth0
    ports:
      - 8500:8500
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  traefik_proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    driver: overlay

volumes:
  consul-data:
      driver: local
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @domiSchenk yes. http://www.traveldiaries4u.com/authorsCollections/fullCollections/softwareCollections/traefik